# How to get authorization code with OWIN, OAuth and Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I followed this post: [Token Based Authentication using ASP.NET Web API 2, Owin, and Identity](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/). Now, I have a Web API standalone "server" able to successfully authenticate users and returns an Access Token when I send username/password to it. Then, I can use the Access Token to access protected data (in the blog post, I can access the Orders).

For now, the client from which I sent username/password to get the Access Token is a Console app.

I want to add a bit more complexity and before getting the Access Token, I would like to get an Authorization Code. But I cannot find any example on how to do it. From what I read, I should send a GET request structured like this:

> /authorize?response_type=code&client_id=< ClientID>

This is what I am doing from my console app:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:63828/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=" + Guid.NewGuid());

    var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

But I get an error message:

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> [HttpException]: The controller for path '/authorize' was not found or does not implement IController.
>      at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

This is the content of the Startup.cs file in the Web API project:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/authorize"),
            ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true,
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
```

What I find weird is that I defined the "/authorize" endpoint but it is not accessible... The "/token" endpoint is accessible and I did not do anything special for this.

Any idea how I can overcome this?

Comment: Did you ever manage to get the authorization code from your authorization endpoint? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A crucial thing to remember when using the OAuth2 authorization server built in Katana is that its authorization endpoint is *pass-through* by default: you must provide your own */authorize* endpoint (using MVC or Nancy for instance) or directly render your consent form in **OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.AuthorizationEndpoint**.

You can take a look at the [official documentation](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server) for a complete walkthrough indicating how you can implement your own MVC controller and your own authorization endpoint.

Comment: For a complete sample, you can also take a look at [this Nancy client/server demo](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server/tree/dev/samples/Nancy). It doesn't use `OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware` but a much more elaborated fork targeting OpenID Connect but you should get the idea.